# Antd Fixed Tabs position in Header and render Tabs content in Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

I want the tabs title to be fixed in in Header Component and Tabs content to be rendered in the Header Component. How do I achieve it ?

Below is the code

```
<Layout className="site-layout">
  <HeaderComponent headerTitle="Profile">
{/* I want the tab pane here and when I click any on the tab pane the tab content should get rendered in the Content component*/}
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
      <TabPane tab="Overview" key="1"></TabPane>
      <TabPane tab="Alerts" key="2"></TabPane>
    </Tabs>
  </HeaderComponent>
  <Content
    className="site-layout-background"
    style={{
      margin: "140px 16px",
      padding: 24,
      minHeight: 280,
    }}
  >
 {/* Display the content of selected tab */}
  </Content>
</Layout>
```

Comment: Have you found the answer?